# Bash : Read lines with non-zero values from a file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file containing a list of numbers with one number per line. I want to find the average value of the non-zero numbers in the file.

Eg: The file is:

```
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
0.0
0.0
```

I want the answer to be 2.0 and not 1.0

I can get this by reading each line, adding it to a sum, increase a count if value is not equal to zero, and in the end calculating sum/count.

Is there a simpler way do this with any other commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this awk one-liner does filtering and average calculation:

```
awk '$0{s+=$0;c++}END{printf "%.1f\n",c?s/c:0}' file
```

it outputs:

```
2.0
```

Comment: As a very minor improvement, you could replace the final `s/c` by `c?s/c:0` (or something similar) in case there are no non-nil values, so as to avoid a division by 0.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you are absolutely right! thank you! I'm gonna update it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -v '0.0' file.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum/NR}'
```

Comment: Why are you grepping and piping to awk when awk can search it self ?